# Newline inside Table

Tags: tables, line-breaking, tabularx

I would like to know how to manually insert a line break inside a table cell. Sometimes, this just looks so much better. However, I have not found anything that helped me out. I tried using \shortstack but the headspace to the horizontal lines is very small.

Here's my code:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
    \resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tabular}{p{4cm} c|c}
            Parameter Category & Mathworks Toolbox & LMN Toolbox \\
            \hline
            Estimation Focus (Prediction or Simulation) & Focus-Parameter & kStepPrediction Value \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        }
    \caption{ARX vs. OE Model Structure}
    \label{tab:modelParameters}
\end{table}
```

I'd like to put '(Prediction or Simulation)' in a new line in the same cell under Estimation Focus.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but please don't use resizebox on tables as it will lead to inconsistent font sizes throughout the document.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you for the tipp, I needed to resize the table for 1 special case which this one is. I cannot imagine of an other way to shrink the table size while retaining the font size. Can you ? :)

Comment: Regarding "shrink the table size while retaining the font size": The recommended way to do so would be reducing the column widths. Either manually or by using `tabularx` that allows you to specify an overall width of your table and adds a flexible width column type that lets your table adapt to this overall width.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you! I will consider it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `p` type column, it's possible to use `\par`. In other column types, you can load the `\makecell` package and use the `\makecell` macro. Otherwise, you can use a small tabular with two rows in that cell.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,makecell}

\begin{document}    

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
    \resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tabular}{m{4cm} c|c}
            Parameter Category & Mathworks Toolbox & LMN Toolbox \\
            \hline
            Estimation Focus\newline(Prediction or Simulation) & \makecell{Focus-Parameter\\Blabla ..} & kStepPrediction Value \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        }
    \caption{ARX vs. OE Model Structure}
    \label{tab:modelParameters}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: thank you for your solution. However, I would also like to make newlines in c columns. Any clue ?

Comment: You can use `makecell` or insert a small tabular as I illustrated in my answer. I'll add an example if you need more help with a specific method.

Comment: it would be really nice if you could add an example. For instance, you could add 'BlaBla' under 'Focus-Parameter'.

Comment: I've added an example, please see my edit.

Comment: thank you! Your solution and the suggested solution from ''How to add a forced line break inside a table cell'' helped me a lot !